# how to execute Grant and Revoke command using JDBC connection

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, statements

I don't know whether I am able to execute the Grant,Revoke query using Jdbc connection.

here is the Code kindly suggest me where am I leading wrong?

```
        query="create user "+username+" identified by "+userpass;
        query1="Grant Connect,Resource,DBA to"+username;
        query2="Grant Create SESSION Grant ANY PRIVILEGE to"+username;
        query3="Grant UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to"+username;
        query4="GRANT Select,Update,Insert on"+TableName+"to"+username;
        System.out.println(query);
        System.out.println(query2);
        System.out.println(query3);
        st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        b=st.execute(query);
        b1=st.execute(query1);
        b2=st.execute(query2);
        b3=st.execute(query3);
        System.out.println(query1+query2+query3);
```

I am getting the following error :

> ORA-00990: missing or invalid privilege

The entire connection and Code is fine .

Comment: `ORA-00990:` **`missing or invalid privilege`**

Comment: You are missing spaces in some of your statements.

Comment: Yeah Thanks for the suggestions I have added the spaces  and query1,query2 executed successfully but query 3 is still giving the error (query3="Grant UNLIMITED TABLESPACE to "+username;)

Comment: actually after execution and compilation I got to know that query3,query4,query5 are giving the Exception. I don't know why they are not getting executed.

Comment: Which exception are you getting now ? Still `'Ora00990` or some other ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue , I just did exit from everything and then executed and magically everything is fine. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

try to write when you are creating user

```
query = "create user '" + username + "'@'localhost' identified by " + userpass;
```

it can help if you are using a local server